# How to override built-in functions in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to apply a python concept in PHP. In python we can override the `__str__` method of a class to change the string representation of an object.

Is there a similar concept in PHP and what does the syntax look like?

Comment: Read the [documentation about magic methods](http://php.net/manual/language.oop5.magic.php), please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__toString()` is what you are looking for.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring

Answer (score 0):

There are a limited number of methods that you can define for a class via the magic methods.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

PHP allows you to define functions for these methods only.  You are not able to override the number of methods like in Python (mathematical operations, comparisons, etc.)